# How to plot failure types stacked next to each other in bar plots using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, reshape2

I have a dataframe like this:

```
ID <- c("A","A","B","B","A","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","B","B","A","A","A","B","B","B")
Measurement <- c("Len","Len","Len","Wid","Ht","Ht","Wid","Len","Ht","Ht"
                 ,"Wid","Ht","Len","Ht","Wid","Len","Wid","Ht","Len","Wid")
STATUS <- c("FAIL","FAIL","FAIL_AVG_HIGH","FAIL","FAIL","FAIL_AVG_HIGH","FAIL#Pts","FAIL","FAIL_AVG_LOW","FAIL"
            ,"FAIL#Pts","FAIL","FAIL_AVG_HIGH","FAIL","FAIL","FAIL_AVG_LOW","FAIL","FAIL_AVG_LOW","FAIL","FAIL#Pts")
df1 <- data.frame(ID,Measurement,STATUS)
```

I am creating 2 columns to get the count of failed measurements per category and creating a MEAS_ID column per category

```
df2 <- dcast(df1, Measurement+ID~STATUS, value.var="STATUS")
df2$Count <- rowSums(df2[3:6])
df2 <- within(df2, MEAS_ID <- paste(Measurement, ID, sep='_'))
```

I then plot the pareto using barplots for each category like this

```
windows()
ggplot(df2, aes(reorder(MEAS_ID,Count), Count)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
  theme(plot.title=element_text(face="bold", size=20)) +
  ggtitle("Count of Failed Measurements") +
  xlab("MEAS_ID") + ylab("Count") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

I would ideally like to plot types of failure (FAIL, FAIL#Pts, FAIL_AVG_HIGH,FAIL_AVG_LOW) stacked next to each other for each category shown above. The problem that am I facing is that since I used "dcast" the type of failures have pivoted from rows into columns and I am not knowing how to include them in ggplot to get 4 sub barplots instead of 1 bar plot for each category. Please let me know if this is not clear.

Kindly provide your inputs to help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `dcast` at all. Instead you can use some fancy magic in `ggplot`:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=paste(Measurement, ID), y=..count.., fill=STATUS)) + geom_bar()
```

If the commenter is correct, and it sounds like they are, you will need to add a little to this to get each category grouped, but not stacked:

```
ggplot(df1, aes(x=paste(Measurement, ID), y=..count.., fill=STATUS)) + geom_bar(position = 'dodge')
```

Comment: I think they also want clustered bars, so should be `+ geom_bar(position = "dodge")`

Comment: @Justin -That is exactly how I wanted it to look. Thank you so much for this awesome one line ggplot way!! and Chris was right. I wanted clustered bar visualization as well. Very helpful.

Comment: @Justin, I am trying to do the following. 1) Order the bar plots in the decreasing order of counts 2) Show only the top 2 that have the highest counts out of the 6 categories. In this case, it would be Ht A & Len B.  I am trying to reorder by doing this ggplot(df1, aes(reorder(paste(Measurement,ID),..count..), ..count.., fill=STATUS)) + geom_bar() but it throws me with an error saying "Error: stat_bin requires the following missing aesthetics: x"  ... Could you please help me with that.

Comment: @Sharath standard procedure would be to (do a lot of research first) and then if you still can't find the answer, open a new question